# adding an onclick event to an already included script

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm using the following javascript on my site - this is a demo: This shows a little popunder at the bottom of the page

https://mylivechat.com/demo/inline-chat.html

I'm wondering if there is any way of putting a onclick event in the popunder, so when it is clicked/opened I can do something with javascript?

Does anyone know how to do this in javascript, where an onclick event can be added to an already included script?

Comment: A [mcve] must be included *in the question itself*, otherwise this is [off-topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Links to your own site are liable to change and make this question no longer useful to future visitors.

Comment: I don't think I can give a better example than the one in question.

Comment: Best way is to include the js event in the same file of the chat script so you make sure that the event will be always included, and then you can do something like `$('.mylivechat_inline').click(function(){
  /* do something*/
});`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a click function to the collapsed section of the inline chat can be done fairly simply, something like:

```js
var mylivechatcollapsed = document.querySelector('div.mylivechat_collapsed');
  mylivechatcollapsed.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("ClickEvent")
  });
```

```html
<div class="mylivechat_inline" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 210px; height: 30px; z-index: 16543210; position: fixed; right: 16px; bottom: 0px;"><div class="mylivechat_collapsed" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid rgb(32, 112, 176); border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 210px; top: 0px; height: 30px; transform: translate(0px, 2.44702e-15px); background-color: rgb(46, 141, 199);"><div class="mylivechat_collapsed_text" style="resize: none; font-size: 15px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding-left: 9px; color: white; position: relative; line-height: 30px; left: 0px; width: 208px; top: 0px; height: 28px;">Chat now</div><div class="mylivechat_sprite" title="Maximize" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; left: 184px; width: 16px; top: 7px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png&quot;); background-position: -4px -148px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div></div><div class="mylivechat_expanded" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid rgb(32, 112, 176); border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 210px; top: 0px; height: 30px; display: none; background-color: rgb(46, 141, 199);"><div class="mylivechat_expanded_text" style="resize: none; font-size: 15px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding-left: 9px; color: white; position: relative; line-height: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px;">Chat now</div><div class="mylivechat_sprite" title="Minimize" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; left: -24px; width: 16px; top: 7px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png&quot;); background-position: -4px -52px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div><div class="mylivechat_sprite" title="End Chat" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; display: none; left: -44px; width: 16px; top: 7px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png&quot;); background-position: -4px -76px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div><div class="mylivechat_sprite" title="Pop-out" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; display: none; left: -64px; width: 16px; top: 7px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png&quot;); background-position: -4px -4px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div></div><div class="mylivechat_container" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border-width: 0px 1px 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(32, 112, 176); position: absolute; box-sizing: border-box; left: 0px; width: 210px; top: 30px; height: 0px; display: none;"><div class="mylivechat_main" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; display: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div class="mylivechat_prechat" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 6px; box-sizing: border-box; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px;"><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; min-height: 100%; overflow: visible; position: relative;"><div class="mylivechat_prechat_logo" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0px 12px 12px;"><img class="mylivechat_prechat_logo_img" src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/Customization/Template/InlineChatOnlineLogo_a3.png"></div><div class="mylivechat_prechat_text" style="resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0px 12px 12px; color: black; line-height: 1.3em; font-size: 13px !important;">Thank you for contacting us. To serve you better please provide the following information:</div><div class="mylivechat_prechat_name" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_prechat_name_lbl mylivechat_prechat_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Name:</label><input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="mylivechat_prechat_name_box mylivechat_prechat_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><div class="mylivechat_prechat_email" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_prechat_email_lbl mylivechat_prechat_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Email:</label><input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="mylivechat_prechat_email_box mylivechat_prechat_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><div class="mylivechat_prechat_oauth" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_prechat_oauth_lbl mylivechat_prechat_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;"></label><div class="mylivechat_prechat_oauth_box mylivechat_prechat_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: right; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: transparent;"><span style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; line-height: 22px;">or sign in with :  </span><span style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; line-height: 22px;"><img src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/icon_google.png" style="margin: 3px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);"></span><span style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; line-height: 22px;"><img src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/icon_facebook.png" style="margin: 3px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);"></span></div></div><div class="mylivechat_prechat_question" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_prechat_question_lbl mylivechat_prechat_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Question:</label><textarea placeholder="Question" class="mylivechat_prechat_question_box mylivechat_prechat_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 50px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: visible; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></textarea></div><div class="mylivechat_prechat_department" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_prechat_department_lbl mylivechat_prechat_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Department:</label><select class="mylivechat_prechat_department_box mylivechat_prechat_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><option value="" style="color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">Choose department</option><option value="Support" style="color: black;">Support</option><option value="Sales" style="color: black;">Sales</option></select></div><div class="mylivechat_prechat_submit" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><button class="mylivechat_prechat_submit_button" style="display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.42857; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; left: -15px; background-image: none;">Start Chat</button></div><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; height: 25px;"></div><div class="mylivechat_poweredby" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 12px; height: 20px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute;"><div class="mylivechat_footer" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="mylivechat_offline" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding-top: 12px; padding-bottom: 6px; box-sizing: border-box; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; position: absolute; display: none; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px;"><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; min-height: 100%; overflow: visible; position: relative;"><div class="mylivechat_offline_logo" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0px 12px 12px;"><img class="mylivechat_offline_logo_img" src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/Customization/Template/InlineChatOfflineLogo_a1.png"></div><div class="mylivechat_offline_text" style="resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0px 12px 12px; color: black; line-height: 1.3em; font-size: 13px !important;">There are no agents available right now to take your call. Please leave a message and we will get back to you soon.</div><div class="mylivechat_offline_name" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_offline_name_lbl mylivechat_offline_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Name:</label><input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="mylivechat_offline_name_box mylivechat_offline_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><div class="mylivechat_offline_email" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_offline_email_lbl mylivechat_offline_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Email:</label><input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="mylivechat_offline_email_box mylivechat_offline_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><div class="mylivechat_offline_oauth" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_offline_oauth_lbl mylivechat_offline_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;"></label><div class="mylivechat_offline_oauth_box mylivechat_offline_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: right; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: transparent;"><span style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; line-height: 22px;">or sign in with :  </span><span style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; line-height: 22px;"><img src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/icon_google.png" style="margin: 3px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);"></span><span style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block; line-height: 22px;"><img src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/icon_facebook.png" style="margin: 3px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);"></span></div></div><div class="mylivechat_offline_subject" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_offline_subject_lbl mylivechat_offline_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Subject:</label><input type="text" placeholder="Question" class="mylivechat_offline_subject_box mylivechat_offline_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 32px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></div><div class="mylivechat_offline_enquiry" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><label class="mylivechat_offline_enquiry_lbl mylivechat_offline_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: none; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; font-weight: normal;">Message:</label><textarea placeholder="Message" class="mylivechat_offline_question_box mylivechat_offline_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 50px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; text-indent: 2px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: visible; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 15px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></textarea></div><div class="mylivechat_offline_submit" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><button class="mylivechat_offline_submit_button" style="display: inline-block; padding: 6px 12px; margin-top: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.42857; text-align: center; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 4px; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; left: -15px; background-image: none;">Send</button></div><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; height: 25px;"></div><div class="mylivechat_poweredby" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; left: 12px; height: 20px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute;"><div class="mylivechat_footer" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="mylivechat_support" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; display: none; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px;"><div class="mylivechat_support_frame" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px;"><iframe frameborder="0" src="about:blank" id="mylivechatinpageframe" style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe></div><div class="mylivechat_survey" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; display: none; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px;"><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; opacity: 0.88; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);"></div><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102); left: 8px; width: 0px; top: 8px; height: 0px; background-color: rgb(249, 250, 250);"><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: rgb(207, 214, 224); left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 5px; height: 28px;"><div class="mylivechat_sprite" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; left: -28px; width: 16px; top: 5px; height: 16px; background-image: url(&quot;https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png&quot;); background-position: -4px -340px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div><div class="mylivechat_survey_title" style="resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0px 12px 12px; color: black; line-height: 28px; font-size: 13px !important;">Live Chat Exit Survey</div></div><div style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 0px; top: 36px; height: 0px; background-color: white;"><div class="mylivechat_survey_header" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding-top: 12px;"><div class="mylivechat_survey_message" style="resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 0px 12px 12px; color: black; line-height: 1.3em; font-size: 13px !important;">To help us serve you better, please provide some information concerning your chat experience.</div></div><div class="mylivechat_survey_rating" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align: center;"><img src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/good.png" style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 10px; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 5px;"><img src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/bad.png" style="width: 48px; height: 48px; margin: 0px 10px; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 5px;"></div><div class="mylivechat_survey_comment" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><div class="mylivechat_survey_comment_lbl mylivechat_survey_lbl" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; display: inline-block; margin: 3px 0px; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 2px; left: 10px; width: 0px;">Comment:</div><textarea class="mylivechat_survey_comment_box mylivechat_survey_box" style="display: inline-block; height: 50px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 6px 5px; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.42857; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); border-radius: 2px; outline: 0px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: visible; resize: none; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; margin: 3px 0px; left: 10px; width: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></textarea></div><div class="mylivechat_survey_butttons" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding: 12px 5px; text-align: center;"><button class="mylivechat_survey_submit_button" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 5px 12px; padding: 3px 12px; width: 80px;">Send</button><button class="mylivechat_survey_cancel_button" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin: 5px; padding: 3px 12px; width: 80px;">Close</button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="mylivechat_bubble" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; top: -79px; height: 76px; left: 2px; overflow: visible; padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 6px;"><img class="mylivechat_bubble_img" src="https://a1.mylivechat.com/Customization/Template/InPageBubbleTop_Online_3.png" style="cursor: pointer;"><div class="mylivechat_sprite" style="resize: none; font-size: 13px; font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; cursor: pointer; right: 0px; top: 0px; width: 16px; height: 16px; display: none; background-image: url(&quot;https://a1.mylivechat.com/livechat2/images/sprite.png&quot;); background-position: -4px -340px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get this to work on my example. Do I have to use the div you have provided at the bottom, rather than the js url from mylivechat?

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't be working.  The <div> code in the example above was lifted from your mylivechat page.  I assume your JS console isn't showing "ClickEvent"?   You also need to make sure that the mylivechat is fully loaded before running the script above.

Answer (score -1):

Add *jQuery* to your page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"><script>
```

Then this *Javascript* code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".mylivechat_inline").click(function() {
        alert("clicked"); //Your code Here
    });
});
```